# trouble implementing card like view in html and css

Tags: html, css

Expected output image illustration:

[image: expected output image illustration]

```css
html, body 
{

    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
html *
{
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
.cand1
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
.cand2
{
    width:50%;
    float: right;
}
.prof1,.prof2
{
    margin:0;
    margin-top: 40;
    text-align: center;
}
.name
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.post
{
    font-weight: bolder;
 

}
.card
{
    
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    
}
h4
{

    
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style_vote.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">

      <div class="card">
        <h4 class="post">Post 1</h4>
        <div class="cand1">
          <div class="prof1">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 1</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cand2">
          <div class="prof2">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 2</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h4 class="post">Post 2</h4>
        <div class="cand1">
          <div class="prof1">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 3</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cand2">
          <div class="prof2">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 4</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h4 class="post">Post 3</h4>
        <div class="cand1">
          <div class="prof1">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 5</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cand2">
          <div class="prof2">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 6</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h4 class="post">Post 4</h4>
        <div class="cand1">
          <div class="prof1">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 7</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cand2">
          <div class="prof2">
            <img src="images/dummy1.jpg">
            <p class="name">Candidate 8</p>
            <p class="add">Class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Current output image:

[image: current output image]
I am trying to implement a card like style with html and css.
the h4 tag in the div card produces spaces ,on using margin 0 and padding 0 in css it produces a white line ,I also couldn't find to split each card,tried margin as well as padding attributes for the card div,doesn't seem to work.

also the attributes i apply on the entire card div doesn't seem to apply on the h4 tag, modifying other attributes such as height on the card div makes the dummy image pop out of the card div section

Comment: please provide a working example instead of images. You can use the Javasscript/HTML snippet feature in the toolbar next to the image button.

Comment: @Christopher Dosin.thanks for pointing out,added the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is pretty messy i created a simple example for you. Hope it helps.

Also try to avoid `!important` to keep your code clean and maintainable.

```css
section {
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

section h4 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card--text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h4>Post</h4>
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" />
        <p class="card--text">
          I am the Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" />
        <p class="card--text">
          I am the Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h4>Post</h4>
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" />
        <p class="card--text">
          I am the Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" />
        <p class="card--text">
          I am the Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```